# Distinguishing between "file in use" and other exceptions in .NET

Tags: .net, exception, file-io, directory

I am reading files from a directory. I need to handle a situation where my application tries to pickup a file which is still being written to by another process, which I have no control over.

I am assuming that by trying to open the file, which is still being written to by something else, I am going to get an exception. Now, I need to figure out whether there is something wrong with the file, in which case I move it to another directory or whether the second process is still writing to the file, in which case I would want to try again in second iteration of reading the directory.

Anyone know how I can distinguish between those two exceptions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Marshal.GetHRForException() method to recover the original Windows error that caused the IOException to be raised.  An example:

```
static FileStream TryOpen(string path, int maxAttempts = 10, int interval = 1000) {
    for (int attempt = 0; ; attempt++) {
        try {
            return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            var err = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(ex) & 0xffff;
            if (attempt < maxAttempts && err != 32) throw;
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception hierarchy is really screwed up in .NET. Tricks like this one should not be necessary.

Comment: No, you are witnessing *good design*.  A .NET programmer still has the option to do the silly thing, if he wants to.  Usually ending up with maxAttempts = 999 or somesuch number, nobody ever picks 666.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: See Hans Passant's answer for an actual good solution. Leaving the Handle tool as a reference because it helps in similar cases.

For a robust way to check whether the file is opened by a specific process you can use [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx). It's a command line tool but you might be able to use it for your situation.

*Old answer*:

One *hacky* solution could be to simple check the exception's message. 
If it includes

> is being used by another process

Then your file is locked by another process (can't tell from the exception which one is it).
Otherwise, it's some other I/O error.

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't seem to say whether an IOException is thrown only on a handle violation (otherwise you'd be able to distinguish by whether the thrown exception is IOException or a derivative like FileNotFoundException).

Sample code:

```
catch (IOException ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Contains("is being used by another process"))
    {
        // Retry logic goes here
    }
    else
    {
        // Other type of error (possibly derivative of IOException)
        throw;
    }
}
```

It's far from perfect, but the system message probably doesn't change too much.

Comment: Exception messages change a lot.  Just run your code on a machine that doesn't speak English.

Comment: Good correction....will update and redirect to your answer as a much  better solution.